# OAuth2 Server and OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am working on a Drupal 7 Based Web Application Development with a core server and multiple client web sites.

The core server will be exposing APIs which will be called from the multiple web sites. The core server will also be the OpenID authentication provider and multiple web sites will use this OpenID.

If a user loges in to the core then the user should be able to use any of these multiple web site with the same authentication.

For this purpose I have decided to use the OAuth2 Server and OpenID Connect modules based. I could not find appropriate tutorial or example even after days of searching the web.

Thus I have the following queries. I would be thankful if the commerce guys or any one who know how to work with these two modules could help me.

1. On the basis of my search and initial implementation I found that one OpenID Connect client will have one authentication Token. But for me each individual login user will have different credential decided by the core server. How can I send this individual credential to the client.
2. Once the user loges using this OpenID then he/she should be able to access the APIs form any of the client without further login.
3. How to transfer the Token that is received by the client in each of the successive calls to the server.
4. Proper way of using OpenID connect and OAuth2 Server for distributed web application and OpenID concept.

I would be grateful, if I could be directed in the right and correct way of working with this concept.